# Permission denied when acl says rwx

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, acl

I changed my server; the old one ran `Centos 8`, the new runs `Ubuntu 20.4`. Now my php scripts have a problem with permissions -- why?

Example:

```
current user: root
script was executed under user: nobody

Message: fopen(/tmp/RebuildCat_sequence.cnt): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Actually this file is owned by `nobody`, so I should not get this warning at all:

```
CS-1 01:47:22 :/tmp# ls -latr /tmp/RebuildCat_sequence.cnt
--wxrwxrwT+ 1 nobody nogroup 480 Oct 23 00:02 /tmp/RebuildCat_sequence.cnt
```

This php file is called by cron (`root`), as a rule, and as I noticed that some similar cron triggered files are owned by `systemd-timesync`, I issued

```
setfacl -m u:systemd-timesync:rwX /tmp
setfacl -m u:nobody:rwX /tmp
```

and even

```
setfacl -R -m u:nobody:rwX /tmp
setfacl -R -m u:systemd-timesync:rwX /tmp
```

to no avail. How do I understand this?

In my understanding both users `systemd-timesync` and `nobody` should be able to read and write files in `/tmp` without problem due to `acl`. I think someone has to educate me here.

`/tmp` resides on `/dev/md2`

```
    CS-1 01:32:34 :/tmp# tune2fs -l /dev/md2 | grep "Default mount options:"
    Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
```

No problem here, I guess.

```
CS-1 01:46:09 :/tmp# getfacl /tmp
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: tmp
# owner: root
# group: root
# flags: --t
user::rwx
user:systemd-timesync:rwx
user:nobody:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::rwx
```

Looks OK to me, as well. Clueless.

#### Addendum

OK, I set `chmod 777 /tmp`, but still I get a `PHP` error  `fopen(/tmp/RebuildCat_sequence.cnt): failed to open stream: Permission denied`, but `file_put_contents` works with `777` -- how do I understand this? Why does `fopen` throw an error, but `file_put_contents` does not?

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It would belong to [su]. But as it turned out to be a trivial oversight, it's not probably not worth moving it. Please consider deleting the question.

Comment: Agreed; but what about the information request?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by *"information request"*.

Comment: I would like to understand -- nothing I found googling gave me an answer to my questions. The whole concept isn't clear to me. BTW, `chmod 676 /tmp` isn't OK at all, for example `mysql` needed 677 (why 7 for a temporary table?), so I finally had to return to 777. You see, there are many questions. Where to put them best? Can I delete this question when I answered myself?

Answer (score 0):

Alas, `chmod 777 /tmp` in the console is **not** the answer. It is much more complicated than that. So I wasn't silly at all.

##### How to reproduce?

In my case, I have 2 docker `PHP` containers writing to a number of case specific log files, one of them using `apache`, the other `nginx`. Both have a mapping `/tmp:/tmp`, so we can look at a file from the host or from inside a container.

From inside the containers, the owner is `apache:apache` if created in the `apache` container or `nginx:nginx` in the `nginx` container, but from the host's perspective it is `systemd-timesync:systemd-journal` for the same file in both cases.

Of course, the `apache` container does not have a user `nginx` and vice versa (neither does the host). So if my `PHP` script wants to write to a file created by the other container, I have said permission problem.

##### Fix

The remedy is easy, if at **creation time** the owner is changed to `nobody` and permissions to `666`.

If not, we cannot change the owner from the other container and get `failed to open stream: Permission denied`. See https://serverfault.com/questions/772227/chmod-not-working-correctly-in-docker (also see the discussion about changing permissions from host via `system` call below).

So I wrote a wrapper function `str_to_file` to add this manipulation:

```
function str_to_file($str, $filename= "/tmp/tmp.txt", $mode="a+") {
    if (!file_exists($filename)){
        touch($filename);           # create file
        chmod($filename, 0666);     # the owner can chmod
        chown($filename, 'nobody'); # the owner can chown
    } # if (!file_exists($filename))

    $mode = $mode == 'w'
        ? LOCK_EX
        :  FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX;

    file_put_contents($filename, $str . PHP_EOL, $mode);
} # str_to_file
```

This works for both the `apache` and `nginx` containers.

##### Explanation

How did I get into this mess anyway?

It looks like either I didn't mess it up when on `CentOS`, so in this case most probably it has nothing to do with my switch to `Ubuntu`. I cannot remember what I did but I don't remember I had this kind of permission problem on `CentOS`.

Or `CentOS` handles files created in a container differently than `Ubuntu`. I am sure I never saw a user `systemd-timesync:systemd-journal` on `CentOS`. Unfortunately I cannot investigate without too much effort what user `CentOS` would substitute from the host point of view and which consequences this has.

Oh wait, I remember I do have another server running `PHP` and `nginx` on `CentOS`. Creating a file in `/tmp` from within the container reveals that the owner from both inside the container and from the host is `nobody`. So there *is* a significant difference between both Linux versions.

What's more, this insight explains why I experienced this permission problem only *after* the switch from `CentOS` to `Ubuntu`, to which I was forced due to the fact that my provider does not offer `CentOS` anymore for obvious reasons.

By the way, I first tried the `CentOS` substitutes `AlmaLinux` and `RockyLinux` with bad results of different nature which finally forced me to use `Ubuntu`. This switch in turn revealed lots of problems, this one being the last, which cost me several weeks so far. I hope that this nightmare ends now.

Acting from `cron`, the `apache` version is and was used exclusively, so no problem here.

Testing from the browser lately, I switched by chance and for no particular reason from the `apache` version to the `nginx` version and vice versa, creating those described problems.

Actually I don't know why the containers write on behalf of those users. The user of the container is `root` in both cases, as is standard with `docker`. I guess it is the browser engine which introduces these users.

Interestingly, when trying to change permissions and ownership via `system` call *after* creation, I failed, if I remember correctly, although the user then should be `root` and `root` should be capable of doing that.

It turns out that on `apache` the `system` user [system('whoami')] is not `root` but `apache`, but the file owner is `apache` where as on `nginx` the system user is `nobody` and the file owner is `nginx`. So changing permissions with `system` should work on `apache` [system("chmod 0666 $filename"); system("chown nobody:nobody $filename");], but not on `nginx`. Alas, it does not work on `apache` either.

Quick check in `apache` container:

```
/tmp # whoami
root
/tmp # ls -la *6_0.ins
-rw-r--r--    1 apache   apache         494 Nov 14 18:25 tmp_test_t6_0.ins
/tmp # su apache chmod 0666 tmp_test_t6_0.ins
This account is not available
```

Sorry, I can't understand this. And no idea about ACL.

##### apache vs. nginx

Why do I use both web server versions in the first place?

Well, the process I invoke processes random data which may take a long time, so chances are that `nginx` times out. This is a well-known `nginx` feature.

Despite all my studies and obvious instructions, I could not manage `nginx` to behave. Geez!

Finally, as an appropriate workaround, I introduced `apache`, which does not have this problem. For decent runtimes it makes no difference, of course.

Comment: As an addendum: to find the browser-owner  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35711/giving-php-permission-to-write-to-files-and-folders proposes `ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1` which, from the host, reveals `systemd+` in my case; from within the apache container replacing `f1` with `f2` reveals `apache`. This article discusses similar problems with Symfony and proposes acl instructions to fix this issue. Beware: AFAICS the quote produces an error `setfacl: Option -m: Invalid argument near character 3`

Comment: I have to correct myself: `chown($filename, 'nobody'); # the owner can chown` is not true. Only root can do this, and root is not usable from within the container.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it looks like I was kind of silly. I'm sure I double checked permissions on `/tmp` in `WinSCP` (`1777`), but I am unsure if I did it in the console.

Now I issued `chmod 777 /tmp` in the console and there it is! This problem is gone. `chmod 666 /tmp` reintroduces the problem. `chmod 676 /tmp` is OK as well.

I googled quite a bit to educate myself about this topic, but frankly I don't understand it. In particular why did I have the problem in the first place and why did ACL not solve the problem? I'd appreciate some enlightenment.

Comment: Actually the problem reappeared. Maybe I found a solution. The file in question had as owner user/group `systemd-journal`. Changing the owner and group to either `root` or `nobody` solved the problem. No idea how this user `systemd-journal` came into play, maybe because a cron job used or created that file. Obviously all permissions have no effect on files owned by that user. Why is that so? When and how does it come into play?

Comment: Well, more precisely these files are in /tmp which is mapped from the containers to the host. It is user `systemd-timesync [100]` and group `systemd-journal [101]`  from the host perspective -- when the file is written by the docker `apache` container -- from within the apache container itself it is `apache :apache`. With `nginx` it is `nobody:nobody` from the host and `nginx:nginx` from within the container. Interestingly, `apache` cannot change permissions and owner on it's own file. This is all totally enigmatic to me.